# Is it true that measles vaccine lead to poor sexual potency for men?

Tags: vaccination, urology, measles

Infectiologist at local medical clinic told me that vaccination against measles is not recommended for men because it harms sexual potency. She said though that it is OK to vaccinate children against measles, but for men it is not good. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

The official stance on this 'issue' is:

> **MMR vaccine side-effects**
>   (Measles, Mumps, and Rubella)
>
> What are the risks from MMR vaccine?
>
> A vaccine, like any medicine, is capable of causing serious problems,
>   such as severe allergic reactions.
>
> The risk of MMR vaccine causing serious harm, or death, is extremely
>   small.
>
> Getting MMR vaccine is much safer than getting measles, mumps or
>   rubella.
>
> Most people who get MMR vaccine do not have any serious problems with
>   it.
>
> **Mild problems**
>
> - Fever (up to 1 person out of 6)
> - Mild rash (about 1 person out of 20)
> - Swelling of glands in the cheeks or neck (about 1 person out of 75)
>
> If these problems occur, it is usually within 6-14 days after the
>   shot. They occur less often after the second dose.
>
> **Moderate problems**
>
> - Seizure (jerking or staring) caused by fever (about 1 out of 3,000 doses)
> - Temporary pain and stiffness in the joints, mostly in teenage or adult women (up to 1 out of 4)
> - Temporary low platelet count, which can cause a bleeding disorder (about 1 out of 30,000 doses)
>
> **Severe problems (very rare)**
>
> Serious allergic reaction (less than 1 out of a million doses) Several
>   other severe problems have been reported after a child gets MMR
>   vaccine, including:
>   - Deafness
>   - Long-term seizures, coma, or lowered consciousness
>   - Permanent brain damage
>
> These are so rare that it is hard to tell whether they are caused by
>   the vaccine.

And this leads to the recommendation:

> [**MMR (Measles, Mumps, & Rubella) Vaccine**](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/mmr.html)
>
> **What You Need to Know**
>
> Why get vaccinated? Measles, mumps, and rubella are serious diseases.
>   Before vaccines they were very common, especially among children.
>
> *Measles*
>  
>   Measles virus causes rash, cough, runny nose, eye irritation, and
>   fever. It can lead to ear infection, pneumonia, seizures (jerking and
>   staring), brain damage, and death.
>
> *Mumps*
>   Mumps virus causes fever, headache, muscle pain, loss of appetite, and
>   swollen glands. It can lead to deafness, meningitis (infection of the
>   brain and spinal cord covering), painful swelling of the testicles or
>   ovaries, and rarely sterility.
>
> *Rubella (German Measles)*
>   Rubella virus causes rash, arthritis (mostly in women), and mild
>   fever. If a woman gets rubella while she is pregnant, she could have a
>   miscarriage or her baby could be born with serious birth defects.
>   These diseases spread from person to person through the air. You can
>   easily catch them by being around someone who is already infected.
>
> Measles, mumps, and rubella (MMR) vaccine can protect children (and
>   adults) from all three of these diseases.
>
> Thanks to successful vaccination programs these diseases are much less
>   common in the U.S. than they used to be. But if we stopped vaccinating
>   they would return.
>
> **Who should get MMR vaccine and when?**
>
> Children should get 2 doses of
>   MMR vaccine:
>
> First Dose: 12-15 months of age Second Dose: 4-6 years of age (may be
>   given earlier, if at least 28 days after the 1st dose) Some infants
>   younger than 12 months should get a dose of MMR if they are traveling
>   out of the country. (This dose will not count toward their routine
>   series.)
>
> Some adults should also get MMR vaccine: Generally, ***anyone 18 years of
>   age or older who was born after 1956 should get at least one dose of
>   MMR vaccine,*** unless they can show that they have either been
>   vaccinated or had all three diseases.
>
> MMR vaccine may be given at the same time as other vaccines.
>
> Children between 1 and 12 years of age can get a "combination" vaccine
>   called MMRV, which contains both MMR and varicella (chickenpox)
>   vaccines. There is a separate Vaccine Information Statement for MMRV.
>
> Some people should not get MMR vaccine or should wait. Anyone who has
>   ever had a life-threatening allergic reaction to the antibiotic
>   neomycin, or any other component of MMR vaccine, should not get the
>   vaccine. Tell your doctor if you have any severe allergies. Anyone who
>   had a life-threatening allergic reaction to a previous dose of MMR or
>   MMRV vaccine should not get another dose. Some people who are sick at
>   the time the shot is scheduled may be advised to wait until they
>   recover before getting MMR vaccine. Pregnant women should not get MMR
>   vaccine. Pregnant women who need the vaccine should wait until after
>   giving birth. Women should avoid getting pregnant for 4 weeks after
>   vaccination with MMR vaccine. Tell your doctor if the person getting
>   the vaccine: Has HIV/AIDS, or another disease that affects the immune
>   system Is being treated with drugs that affect the immune system, such
>   as steroids Has any kind of cancer Is being treated for cancer with
>   radiation or drugs Has ever had a low platelet count (a blood
>   disorder) Has gotten another vaccine within the past 4 weeks Has
>   recently had a transfusion or received other blood products Any of
>   these might be a reason to not get the vaccine, or delay vaccination
>   until later.

Which leads to the conclusion that there might have been a slight misunderstanding in doctor-patient communication? As a very, very rare reaction this is a perfectly possible secondary outcome scenario. (Meaning two things here. First: this might be caused only indirectly, because two: if you have a reaction or experience more serious [side-effects](https://www.rxlist.com/m-m-r-ii-side-effects-drug-center.htm) it is more than likely that these performance issues are not of primary concern)

As something to base a general recommendation *against vaccination for men* this seems implausible, to say the least. If this is indeed a [myth](https://www.rund-ums-baby.de/kinderarzt/Macht-die-Masern-Impfung-wirklich-impotent_328350.htm) portrayed  accurately than some more [reading](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4547299/) might be [required](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4748339/).

Regarding sexual and reproductive health this vaccine actually improves [outcomes](https://www.sharedjourney.com/mumps-and-male-infertility.html) in preventing mumps related swollen testes ([mumps orchtitis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1633545/)) and [infertility](http://www.hkmj.org/abstracts/v21n1/5.htm) (from [mumps epididymitis](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(06)68274-3/fulltext)) , and possibly [impotence](https://ehealthforum.com/health/sexual-satisfaction-after-mumps-t228238.html) (erectile disfunction).